AirPods Icon in Status Bar
Some time ago, there was an AirPods icon in the statusbar of macOS, to show the battery percentage and toggle between the different noise control modes, like in this screenshot. However, after an update this has been removed. Is there a way to get it back, or has it gone for good? Thanks in advance!

How did you make it appear the first time?

I always appeared automatically once they paired to my mac.
